# Py: OpenCV: How to detect if image matches another image / color in the left bottom corner?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use opencv, whether on LinkedIn account thumbnails in the left bottom corner green-olive color / pixels is to be detectable. (opentowork hashtag)

Example image:

[image]

Piece to find:

[image]

Example without #opentowork:

[image]

I have tried to match templates, but the result is really unreliable:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import imutils


original = cv2.imread('orig.jpg', 0) # Piece to find
train_img = cv2.imread('1516535608688.jpg', 0) # Example image

print(cv2.matchTemplate(train_img, original, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED).max())
```

Then I googled and find out how to detect coordinates:

```
img1 = imutils.resize(train_img)
img2 = img1[197:373,181:300]  #roi of the image

indices = np.where(img2!= [0])
coordinates = zip(indices[0], indices[1])
```

I am using opencv like the first and the last time and have no idea (and don't need it in the future) how to proceed.

Comment: can you please clarify which variable contains which picture? "train" seems to be your template, and "original" seems to be a portrait with the overlay? please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: you don't "detect coordinates". coordinates are not something that is "detected". -- take the template image and then a ROI from the portrait where that template would be expected. then calculate `diff = cv.absDiff(template, roi)` of both. then you can check the fraction of pixels that are "close to equal", like so: `fraction_similar = (diff <= 10).mean()`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry, yeah, I have added comments to the code
orig is this green small image and train_img is the first one (with the whole hashtag)

Comment: "Piece to find" you showed, you can search that piece in the whole image but now with "match templates". You may check it easily pixel by pixel